# Gambler's ruin: monotonicity of winning time as function of $p$

Tags: calculus, markov-chains

In the gambler's ruin problem let: player A have initial capital $k$ and probability of winning $p$,   player B have initial capital $n-k$ and probability of winning $q=1-p$. It is well known that, for $p\ne q$, the probability of player A winning is $u_k(s) = \frac{1-s^k}{1-s^n}$, where $s=q/p$.

**QUESTION**:  How to prove $u_k(s)$ is a decreasing function of $s$? I can think of various "Markov Chain" based proofs but I am looking for a simple (?) calculus-based (?) proof. Any help will be appreciated.

PS. The farthest I have come is an informal argument of the form: in $\frac{1-s^k}{1-s^n}$, when $s$ increases, so does $1-s^k$ but $1-s^n$ increases more (so the fraction decreases). But putting this into rigorous terms has proved to be very elusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $n>k>0$, the function $f : x \mapsto x^{k/n}$ from is strictly concave on $\mathbb{R}+$, so
$$\frac{f(s^n)-f(1)}{s^n-1} = \frac{s^k-1}{s^n-1},$$
namely the slope of the chord joining the points $(1,1)$ and $(s^n,s^k)$, is a decreasing function of $s$.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much sir! This was exactly the type of result I was hoping for.

Comment: @kehagiat Do you know how to accept an answer?